# connect my google accont in a new device

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I use my google account with a PC and with an ASUS tablet.
Now I'm trying to connect a new smartphone (new for me... it was the old phone of my daughter...)
First of all, I resetted the device to the farm setting, and now when I try to define my account I always receive a message like this "account or password not valid... "
Of course the account and the password are correct...
I need some other settings on the phone? any idea
Thanks in advance, for your help
The smartphone is a Samsung GT-S5670
Android version 2.3.6
Kernel version 2.6.35.7-1210226
Build version GINGERBREAD.XWKTO

RedKite

Answer (score 0):

> I need some other settings on the phone?

Nope. No other setting is required. You should be able to login fine with the credentials.
I'd recommend double checking the password you typed for any mistake or just reset password incase you may have forgotten.